# Recursive many-to-many CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am not a DB expert was trying to write cte for below scenario for sql server 2012 but could not resolve my problem. Appreciate if some one help me to figure this out.

I am having a many to many table called Jockcard2Item for for the tables Jobcard and items.

Jobcard may have multiple items and items can have many Jobcards,

in my case I want to find out all the Jobcards for given item id like bellow.

- jobcard1 having item 1, item 2.
- jobcard2 having item 2, item 3
- jobards3 having item 3
- jobcard4 having item 4

> I want to get all jobcards associated to given item, if there other
>   items which is refering the same jobcard (like jobcard2 referring
>   item2) want to include that job cards too.
>
> result should return  jobcard1,jobcard3,jobcard3,

I was trying with below query which is running infinite.

```
DECLARE @itemId int
SELECT @itemId = 12

;WITH temp as(
    SELECT jobCard_ID, item_id FROM Jobcard2Item
    WHERE item_id = @EstimateID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bi.jobCard_ID ,bi.item_id  FROM Jobcard2Item
    JOIN temp x ON bi.jobCard_ID= x.jobCard_ID where x.item_id  not IN (bi.item_id )
)

select * from temp option (maxrecursion 0)
```

sample date as bellow

```html
id    jobcard_ID, item_ID
1     512         12
2     512         13
3     513         13
4     513         14
5     514         14
6     515         15
7     516         16
```

when I pass the 12 as item_ID it should return the result - 512,513,514,

Comment: Providing sample data would help a lot.

Comment: Just added sample data. can you have a look at please.

Answer (score 1):

This query should help:

```
select distinct A.jobcard_id from Jockcard2Item A join Jockcard2Item B
on A.jobcard_id = B.jobcard_id or A.item_id = B.item_id
where A.item_id <> B.item_id or A.jobcard_id <> B.jobcard_id
```

It doesn't require CTE (I tried, but I think it's impossible).